# Changing color of a view when animation repeats

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-interface, animation

I have an animation which simulates "pulsing" view, it first transforms it to be infinitely small(invisible) and then it grows back.

```
func addPulsing() {
    println("Added")
    let pulsing = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    pulsing.duration = 0.8

    pulsing.values = [1.0,0.0,1.0]
    pulsing.keyTimes = [0.0,0.4,0.8]

    pulsing.removedOnCompletion = false
    pulsing.repeatCount = HUGE
    pulsing.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced



    let layer = customView.layer
    layer.addAnimation(pulsing, forKey: "pulsing")
}
```

I want to change the color of the view each time the animation repeats. How can I do it ? I tried to use a timer but it gets desynchronized with animation.

UPDATE:

Tried to do something like this:

```
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(3.2, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModePaced | .Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = transform
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.4, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = identity
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[1]
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.8, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = transform
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1.2, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = identity
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[2]
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1.6, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = transform
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2.0, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = identity
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[3]
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2.4, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = transform
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2.8, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = identity
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[0]
        })
    }, completion: nil)
```

still doesn't work as needed. In details animation is all jumpy and not smooth some parts are slower then needed, other are too fast. I want the color to change instantly, when the view shrinks to 0 scale, and then it starts growing with a new background color.

Then I tried to create two separate animations. One for scale and one for color. I made the color one to be discrete in order to change colors instantly. So I got:

```
    let transform = CGAffineTransformScale(customView.transform, 0, 0)
    let identity = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModePaced | .Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = transform
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.4, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.transform = identity
        })
    }, completion: nil)


    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(2.8, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModeDiscrete | .Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[1]
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.4, relativeDuration: 0.8, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[2]
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1.2, relativeDuration: 0.8, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[3]
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2.0, relativeDuration: 0.8, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.customView.backgroundColor = self.colors[0]
        })
    }, completion: nil)
```

For some reason, it just jumps from color 1 to color 0 and doesn't change to colors 2 and 3 at all. And even this transition between 1 and 0 is desynchronized. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem in the two animations approach and actually the problem in my approach as whole was that I didn't know/notice that relative times in the key frames are specified in the interval between 0 and 1, hence they are the fractions of the duration, while I thought they are "exact" times at which things should happen. As a result, I solved this problem, using two animations and setting correct timings.

Comment: Code? Would be helpful to see how you actually solved this.

Answer (score 1):

you could add a function that creates random uicolors.

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

        var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)

    }
```

and use it from within your func

```
func addPulsing() {
    println("Added")
    let pulsing = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    pulsing.duration = 0.8

    pulsing.values = [1.0,0.0,1.0]
    pulsing.keyTimes = [0.0,0.4,0.8]

    pulsing.removedOnCompletion = false
    pulsing.repeatCount = HUGE
    pulsing.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced

    //set background color
    customView.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
    let layer = customView.layer
    layer.addAnimation(pulsing, forKey: "pulsing")
}
```

here is the [source](http://classictutorials.com/2014/08/generate-a-random-color-in-swift/)

Comment: How does that change color of the view when animation repeats ?

Comment: are you calling this method every time the animation happens?

Comment: No, this method only creates an animation and adds it to the layer of the view

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to recreate the animation for each loop, and then after each animation, set the color of your view.

```
// add the first animation
func firstAnimation() {
    let pulsing = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulsing.delegate = self

    pulsing.duration = 0.4
    pulsing.values = [1.0,0.0]
    pulsing.keyTimes = [0.0,1.0]

    pulsing.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced

    let layer = customView.layer
    layer.addAnimation(pulsing, forKey: "pulsing")
}

// continous pulsing animation constructor
func pulsingAnimation() -> CAAnimation {
    let pulsing = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulsing.delegate = self

    pulsing.duration = 0.8

    pulsing.values = [0.0,1.0,0.0] // invert the scale
    pulsing.keyTimes = [0.0,0.4,0.8]

    pulsing.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
}

// then in the delegate, continue looping
func animationDidStop(_ theAnimation: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    customView.backgroundColor = // a new color
    customView.layer.addAnimation(pulsingAnimation(), forKey: "pulsing")
}
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that animationDidStop and didStart methods are called on the main thread which is often blocked by UI stuff. As a result, animation freezes with this approach, while it should run on its separate thread.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but all UI changes, animations included, should be updated on the main thread. that said aside, did your animation stutter between the loops?

Comment: That is correct, however in my situation the main thread gets blocked by a lot of heavy drawing and layout for 1-2 seconds. Therefore, I needed to find the way to make this animation repeatable and correct without running  my code on the main thread.